# How to use Java to close a Windows Explorer Window?

Tags: java, windows, windows-explorer

My Java app creates and deletes a directory `Dir_X`. Somehow I've noticed when I have a Windows Explorer Window open and pointing at that directory, my Java app won't run properly, so I used Java to list all the processes and get the PID for the process `explorer.exe` and killed it.

But this would kill the main task bar at the bottom of the desktop Windows Explorer, that's not what I want.

I just want to close any Windows Explorer Window that is open, so my Java app can create and delete `Dir_X` without a problem, so my question is: how do I use Java to close a Windows Explorer Window?

Comment: I would recommend approaching this problem in a different way: what can you do in Java to detect that the file/folder you're trying to delete is locked in another process and notify the user of your application?

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need it to notify me, it needs to force close them if there is any one open, just do it from the Java app.